# How to switch components using navigation in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am developing a landing page using React. It should have the same navigation bar for all sections and change only its active state.

In App.js file I have used BrowserRouter that routes to Navigation component. My problem is that that Navigation does not work properly, it does not switch components, it switches only pathname. For example when I press Cabinet, it should switch from Home to Cabinet component. Should I use another router for Navigation or not? What would be the best solution for this?

I have tried to create NavRouter component, where I have placed routers for Navigation.

App.js file:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={ Navigation }></Route>
        <Route path='/cabinet' component={ Navigation }></Route>
        <Route path='/catalog' component={ Navigation }></Route>
        <Route path='/company' component={ Navigation }></Route>
        <Route path='/contacts' component={ Navigation }></Route>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Navigation file:

```
class Navigation extends Component {
render() {
const { classes, location: {pathname}, children  } = this.props;
return (
  <div>

  <MuiThemeProvider theme={color}>
  <Fragment>
  <nav id="menu">
  <ul  className="navigation">
  <li>
      <MenuItem component={Link} to='/' selected={'/' === pathname} className="active menuItem" className={classes.menuItemColor}>
          Главная
      </MenuItem>
    </li>
    <li>
      <MenuItem component={Link} to='/cabinet' selected={'/cabinet' === pathname} className="menuItem" className={classes.menuItemColor}>
          Кабинет
      </MenuItem>
      </li>
      <li>
      <MenuItem component={Link} to='/catalog' selected={'/catalog' === pathname} className="menuItem" className={classes.menuItemColor}>
          Каталог
      </MenuItem>
      </li>
      <li>
      <MenuItem component={Link} to='/company' selected={'/company' === pathname } className="menuItem" className="">
          Компания
      </MenuItem>
      </li>
      <li>
      <MenuItem component={Link} to='/contacts' selected={'/contacts' === pathname} className="menuItem" className="">
          Контакты
      </MenuItem>
      </li>
      </ul>

  </nav>
  <main className={classes.content}>
        { children }
    </main>
    </Fragment>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
 }
}
```

NavRouter.js file:

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Navigation>
     <Switch>
         <Route path='/' exact component={ Navigation }></Route>
         <Route path='/home' component={ Home }></Route>
     </Switch>
     </Navigation>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: all your routes poiniting to the Navigation Component, i don't really understand the code, why not in Navigation.js specify each path with its component instead of passing Navigation for all of them

Comment: Because If I indicate path with its components in App.js, it will not show Navigation. It will display only corresponding components without navigation. That is problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by creating Root.js file, where I have placed my components

```
class Root extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <MainNavigation />
    <TopNav />
    {this.props.children}
    </div>
);
}
}
```

And in App.js file I have placed this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Root>
          <Route path='/' exact component={ Home } />
          <Route path='/cabinet' component={ Cabinet } />
          <Route path='/catalog' component={ Catalog } />
          <Route path='/company' component={ Company } />
          <Route path='/contacts' component={ Contacts } />
        </Root>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

create a file called `Routes.js`

in Routes.js:

```
export default () => (
        <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={ Home }></Route>
            <Route path='/cabinet' component={ Cabinet }></Route>
            <Route path='/catalog' component={ Catalog }></Route>
            <Route path='/company' component={ Company }></Route>
            <Route path='/contacts' component={ Contacts }></Route>
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

in App.js

```
    import Routes from './Routes';
    import Navigation from './Navigation'
    //inside render
    <Navigation>
        <Routes />
    </Navigation>
```

**Note**: to get the current pathName, you have to use a state management solution like Redux.

**Or**: if you are not familiar with redux, for now instead of pathname in Navigation component you can use `window.location.pathname`

Comment: It gives an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined" in Navigation component inside render

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to you need to do it. Separate the header navigation from the other components.

> App.js

```
   <Navigation/>
   <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={ Home }></Route>
            <Route path='/cabinet' component={ Cabinet }></Route>
            <Route path='/catalog' component={ Catalog }></Route>
            <Route path='/company' component={ Company }></Route>
            <Route path='/contacts' component={ Contacts }></Route>
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```